# Further to Importing a dynamically generated Python-2.7.13 module (Python recipe)

Tags: python, python-2.7, dynamic, import

There is a recipe here:

[How to import a dynamically generated Python module](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/82234-importing-a-dynamically-generated-module/)

Which I would like to extend as a question.

Q1> can I use functions from the imported module thus:

```
myModule = "myPythonScriptName"
```

Here I do the import calisthenics using ONLY the variable 'myModule'.
Then can I do this?

```
myResult = myModule.myScriptFunction(selfArg, myArguments, ....)
```

And then there is:

Suppose I have a very small web site written in Python running on an Arduino YUN shield on which client1 accesses POSTform1 which calls myScript1.py to process the returned data. Using the above recipe I add code to the webserver to import myScript1.py, processing of the data proceeds according to plan.

Q2> Can I now unimport/unload/get-rid-of the module created from myScript1.py and reclaim its resources - with the thought in mind that there will finish up being a number of such modules involved with the web server?

Q3> What happens when client2 accesses POSTform1 if myScript1 hasn't been unimported as in Q2? I presume in such circumstance I will have to detect that `myScript1.py` has previously been imported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recipe you link to is from 2001.

You can use `types.ModuleType` to create a module and add it to `sys.modules`:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import types

mymodule = types.ModuleType('mymodule', 'dynamically generated')

code = """
def add(a, b):
    return a + b
"""
exec code in mymodule.__dict__
# Python 3: exec(code, mymodule.__dict__)
import sys
sys.modules[mymodule.__name__] = mymodule
```

Now you should be able to import it in another module:

```
import mymodule as m

print(m.add(3, 4))
```

Output:

```
7
```

Some kind of un-import :

```
del sys.modules['mymodule']
del globals()['m']
del globals()['mymodule']
```

Use the name `m` or `mymodule`depending on the name you use to import it in the module you are in.

Now:

```
print(m.add(3, 4))

NameError: name 'm' is not defined
```